# Laravel storage link doesn't work after i push on github

Tags: laravel, github

so i just create a storage link with

```
php artisan storage:link
```

to store images and view them, but after i push it with github, the storage link seems to disappear on my partner's side, so he can only store and can't view, is there a way to fix this without doing the artisan command on his side

Comment: you probably need to make `symlink` again.

Comment: you mean 'php artisan storage:link' on his side?

Comment: Yes, when you `push` your code on github or any other repository, storage link disappears.
and after `clone` you again need to make `symlink`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your partner  has no `ssh`/`terminal`  access, then create symbolic link with `Route`,  run it once  & delete it.

**route/web.php**  :

```
Route::get('/sym', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

Comment: is there a way so that if a new guy join the repository he only need to pull?

Comment: Then push this code on the repo, and they need to call it once to make the symbolic link on their machine.

Comment: yeah i guess there's no way to just push the symlink to our repository

Answer (score 0):

It's just a symbolic link that is created. Seeing that the base folder is not versioned during `php artisan storage:link` the symbolic link will also not be versioned. Your partners will have to face a `php artisan storage:link` at their level. However, it will not be able to access your files unless you decide to version the folder.

Comment: i'm sorry but what's "version the folder" mean?

Comment: Authorize the contents of the folder to be pushed.